# How to do date operations with Eloquent supporting multiple databases?

Tags: doctrine-orm, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm developing a system that will support at least two databases: **MySQL** and **SQLite**.

And I'm wondering how can I *safely* do date operations with Eloquent, such as date diff, add/sub days, add/sub months and so on.

Currently I have the following code, that works, but I want to still believing on finding a better way.

```php
$database = Config::get('database.default');
$yesterdaySql;

if ($database == 'sqlite') 
{
    $yesterdaySql = 'datetime(\'now\', \'-1 day\')';
}
else if ($databse == 'mysql') 
{
    $yesterdaySql = 'subdate(current_date, 1)';
}
```

Is there another way of doing that without explicitly using raw and proprietary SQL statements? I would love to see something like:

```php
$yesterdaySql = Model::where('date', DB::addDays(-1));
// DB will generate the proper raw SQL.
```

---

Doing some research, I found that Doctrine has a `Doctrine\DBAL\Platform\AbstractPlatform` class that contains methods such as: `getDateDiffExpression`, `getDateAddDaysExpression` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses Carbon to work with Date objects.

You should either pass date strings in a Y-m-d format or work with DateTime/Carbon objects.

From the docs:

> When a column is considered a date, you may set its value to a UNIX
>   timetamp, date string (Y-m-d), date-time string, and of course a
>   DateTime / Carbon instance.
>   By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at, updated_at, and
>   deleted_at columns to instances of Carbon, which provides an
>   assortment of helpful methods, and extends the native PHP DateTime
>   class.

See this: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators